# error editext it cannot focus perticular thing in customized layout(from mysql database) in base adapter

Tags: android, web-services

Hello sir  i am fetching the itemnames from database in customized list view append to the edittext.after compailing all the itemnames append to the `edittext` .

if i want change itemname  menas i am clciking on edittext it focus on another `edittext`

my code:

```
public class EditMainMenulistview extends BaseAdapter {
protected static Context Context = null;
int i;
public String editnewmainmenu, menuname, edittext;
String qrimage;
Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
Bitmap[] bmps;
Activity activity = null;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private ImageView[] mImages;
String[] itemimage;
TextView[] tv;
String itemname, itemcode;
public String[] itemnames, itemcodes;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public EditMainMenulistview(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    Context = context;
    // inflater =
    // (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.bmps = new Bitmap[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemnames = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemcodes = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];

    try {

        for (i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
            qrimage = image.getString("menuimage");
            itemname = image.getString("menuname");
            itemcode = image.getString("menucode");
            itemnames[i] = itemname;
            itemcodes[i] = itemcode;

            byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0, qrimageBytes.length);
            int width = 100;
            int height = 100;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
            bmps[i] = bmp;

            mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

            mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

            // tv[i].setText(itemname);
        }
        System.out.println(itemnames[i]);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    View vi = convertView;

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editmainmenulist, null);

    final EditText text = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.editmaimenu);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);
    text.requestFocus();
    image.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);
    text.append(itemnames[position]);
    String edittext = text.toString();

    // Toast.makeText(Context, edittext, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return vi;

}
```

please the mention above code if any one can replay means really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using text.requestFocus() in getview(). Suppose you have 10 items visible in listview getview is called 10 times. so text.requestFocus() is also called 10times so the focus will be on last visible item

Comment: if i am delete text.requestFocus() also same problem occur.